# file_exist не видит файл

Tags: php, файлы

```
define('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
$file_path_exel = (SITE_ROOT . "/temp/" . $this->client['id'] . ".xlsx");
if (file_exists($file_path_exel)) { 
   echo "i'm found!";
}
```

Файл не находится. Пробовал по разному работать с переменной и без `SITE_ROOT ("/temp/" . $this->client['id'] . ".xlsx"` и `"temp/" . $this->client['id'] . ".xlsx")`, но безуспешно.

Файл загружен и перемещен с папку.

Comment: Вы хотяб сказали что приходит в константу SITE_ROOT, и как он видит строчку (SITE_ROOT."/temp/".$this->client['id'].".xlsx")

Comment: Выведете в браузер содержимое переменной $file_path_exel, чтобы понять откуда код пытается файл проверить.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));видит так - C:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\stas\sk_bonus\app\pages\cabinet/temp/4.xlsx

Comment: не знаю в чем прикол,но сегодня все работает,а ничего не менял......

Comment: Я тут вижу слеши не правельные, / \, выберите хотябы один:) или сделайте замену слешей, помню это с виндовским сервером всегда

Answer (score 3):

**Разумеется**, проблема не в функции file_exists, которая прекрасно видит любые файлы.
А в переданном к ней пути и/или реальном существовании файла по этому пути.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_path_exel = (SITE_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."temp" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->client['id'] . ".xlsx");
```